# Nginx redirect for -only- homepage of old domain, to homepage of new domain

Tags: magento2, redirect, nginx, 301-redirect

On the `server.rewrites` file within the `nginx/` map, I have the following logic for redirecting the homepage of an old domain, to the homepage of a new domain:

```
if ($http_host ~ ^(www\.)?olddomain.com ) {
   return 301 https://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

This is not working as expected, because all other url's inside the old domain are also being redirected.

Example: `olddomain.com/someurl` is being redirected to `newdomain.com/someurl`, and the redirect should only work for the home page.

Any ideas on how I could adjust the above mentioned code? Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: location = / { }, location = /index.php { }, location = /index.html { },

Answer (score 0):

in your server block for specific domain change root location to:

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://www.newdomain.com/;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

```
Let’s illustrate the above by an example:

location = / {
    [ configuration A ]
}

location / {
    [ configuration B ]
}

location /documents/ {
    [ configuration C ]
}

location ^~ /images/ {
    [ configuration D ]
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    [ configuration E ]
}
```

> The “/” request will match configuration A, the “/index.html” request
>   will match configuration B, the “/documents/document.html” request
>   will match configuration C, the “/images/1.gif” request will match
>   configuration D, and the “/documents/1.jpg” request will match
>   configuration E.
>
> The “@” prefix defines a named location. Such a location is not used for a regular request processing, but instead used for request
>   redirection. They cannot be nested, and cannot contain nested
>   locations.

Comment: Hi: thanks for your answer :) how would you tackle it if we have different stores views with different domains each one?